# Was it intentional that the conversion operator template<typename T> T&&() is a conversion to an rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I was writing a conversion operator that was to convert a class to an lvalue or an rvalue. So I assumed that:

```
struct C
{
    int x;

    template<typename T>
    operator T&&() {
      return std::forward<T>(x);
    }
};

int main() {
  C x;
  int&& rv_i  = std::move(x);
  int   rv_i2 = x;
  //int&  rv_i3 = x; // fails
}
```

would have added both.  I was surprised that it instead only added a conversion operator which converted to an rvalue of type `T`.  Was that intentional by the standard or is this a bug in g++, clang++ and VC++?

Because of this, it yet again, requires duplication of more functions. :(

Comment: FWIW, There is `std::move` that will always give you an rvalue and `std::forward` that will conditionally give you one.  Do you have a use case where those don't suffice?

Comment: that doesn't even compile.

Comment: Conversion operator to ref is not immediate context, so it's not a forwarding reference unfortunately. Also the area is unclear in the standard. [I've been bitten by that recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52652103/template-conversion-operator-difference-between-clang-6-and-clang-7).

Comment: @Swordfish, sorry. Typo.  Added additional code for a more complete example.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot, what do you mean by "not in an immediate context"?

Comment: @Adrian sorry, I meant deduced context. The mechanism choosing what `T` is for a template conversion operator is not the same as template deduction.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're asking the wrong question.

First let's cover the value-category angle. The result of calling your operator is an lvalue if it returns `T&`, a prvalue if it returns `T`, and an xvalue if it returns `T&&` ([ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)).

What you really want to know is what type your operator returns, given the usage of what looks like a universal reference. However, it's *not* a universal reference. A function argument of type `T&&` would be a universal reference, but that doesn't make the type `T&&` some sort of magic chameleon. Here you are returning an rvalue-ref-to-`T`, period. Per the above, that results in an xvalue (a kind of rvalue).

Now that we know the operator is doing what it's supposed to, how can we do things differently? That really depends on what you're trying to accomplish, which was not fully stated. But it is likely that you're looking for [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) or [`std::forward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward).

Comment: Updated question's example.

Comment: Yes, I quickly figured out that it wasn't a universal reference.  However, as it's in a type deduction context like a parameter, it would make sense that it would be treated as such.

Comment: @Adrian _"it's in a type deduction context like a parameter"_ Is it?

Comment: How is it not @LightnessRacesinOrbit? The type that it is being converted to has to be deduced. When I say `int&& rv_i = std::move(x);` the compiler has to deduce that I'm trying to convert `x` to a `int&&`,

Comment: If not like a parameter, then in a similar fashion.

Comment: @Adrian That's not deduction. You request a conversion to a specific thing. The template is then instantiated to provide the conversion operator for that specific thing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit _Is it?_ [Isn't it?](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.conv)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Bah, maybe

Comment: @Adrian _However, as it's in a type deduction context like a parameter, it would make sense that it would be treated as such._ With forwarding reference, the type used for deduction is based on argument expression's value category (`A&` for lvalues and `A` for rvalues, where `A` is the type of an expression). With conversion operator, there is no argument expression, only the type requested as the result of the conversion. No expression == no value category.

Comment: It's absolutely ludicrous that one must study and comprehend such esoteric wording in order to comprehend the fundamentals of a programming language.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit forgot to relogin?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer What do you mean?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer, I'm not a language lawyer, but It _feels_ like this should be a deduction as there is something asking for a template to be instantiated based on a type (for parameter templates, the type is a passed parameter, for a conversion, it is the conversion requested).  Maybe I'm just jaded that I have to do so many copies of the same function, just to get the class to do what I want.  Currently at 32 copies when including all cv and ref qualifiers.  Had to use a few macros in concert to reduce it to a manageable 6 copies.